# How to make loop for many same type components?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse (Android + Java) and I have 20 components on the Form (20x ImageView).
The names of the ImageViews (I mean @id) looks like:
button1, button2, button3 etc

and now I want to use the loop to change graphics on them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
button (and what here?).setImageResource(R.drawable.grafika);    
}
```

but I don't know how to do this in the loop.
Without loop I can do this:

```
button1.setImageResource(R.drawable.grafika);
button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.grafika);
button3.setImageResource(R.drawable.grafika);
button4.setImageResource(R.drawable.grafika);
//etc
```

but I would like to use one loop that looks like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
{
("button" + i).setImageResource(R.drawable.grafika); //i as string
}
```

How do I do that? If you can, please help me, I will be very happy.

Comment: you should have used an array list go buttons instead of naming them as button1 button2 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the resource ids dynamically, using the code below:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
{
  int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("button"+i , "id", getPackageName());
  ((ImageView) findViewById(resID)).setImageResource(R.drawable.grafika);
}
```

Although, not sure how performant this will be.